# Windows LoadCursor - Does it return the same HCURSOR value each time?

Tags: c++, winapi, cursor

If I call `LoadCursor` multiple times - loading both my own ones or the standard ones - does it return the same `HCURSOR` value if the `ipCursorName` parameter to the function is the same?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: try it out by yourself...

Comment: @MichaelWalz - I have tried it out and it seems to work - but that does not guarantee that it will always be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648391.aspx):

> The LoadCursor function loads the cursor resource only if it has not been loaded; otherwise, it retrieves the handle to the existing resource.